# Zend database connection failure

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, database-connection

Ok I am having real difficulty solving this. I'm trying to connect to a mysql database from a zend application and i receive the following error:

```
Message: No database adapter present
```

I have checked and double checked the connection credentials and they should be fine. The code should be fine too as it works ok in the development environment. If I deliberately change the password to be incorrect in the development environment, I get exactly the same error, which leads me to believe that maybe this is the case, despite my checking!

Any thoughts would be very welcome. If there's nothing obviously wrong here then maybe I need to look at the server/db/php settings?

Thanks!

Bootstrap code:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
protected function _initPlaceholders(){
    Zend_Session::start();

    $this->bootstrap('View');
    $view = $this->getResource('View');

    $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');

    // Set the initial stylesheet:
    $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/global.css');

    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader->registerNamespace('Pog_');


    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers/helpers',
        'Application_Controller_Action_Helper_');

}


}
```

Config file:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.view[] =
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.view.helperPath.View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"
database.adapter         = pdo_mysql
database.params.host     = localhost
database.params.username = user
database.params.password = password
database.params.dbname   = test
```

DB connection helper:

```
/**
 * Constructor: initialize plugin loader
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    try{

        $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini', 'production');
        $dbAdapter = Zend_Db::factory($config->database);
        $dbAdapter->getConnection();
        $this->connection = $dbAdapter;
    } catch (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception $e) {
        echo 'perhaps a failed login credential, or perhaps the RDBMS is not running';
    } catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
        echo 'perhaps factory() failed to load the specified Adapter class';
    }
}
public function getDbConnection(){
    return $this->connection;
}
}
```

Index:

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
|| define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
|| define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
APPLICATION_ENV,
APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
        ->run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your database as a resource

```
resources.db.adapter = pdo_mysql
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = user
resources.db.params.password = password
resources.db.params.dbname = test
```

In your main files you then need to do nothing but initiate a query without having to worry about assigning the database fvrom your config - its done in the inside, the DB resource is always chosen as the default adapter for your database transactions

Comment: Thanks Sam. So what would I have in my DB Connection Helper? Or do you mean that I wouldn't need that at all... I would just directly call queries in the code and the connection would be handled for me?

Comment: Just try it ;) As far as my understanding goes, zend_db_Query / _Select works with default adapters. So the DB-Resource in the config file should work. Personally i use the Table-Data-Gateway so i don't do manual queries at all. PS: it is of utmost importance that you define the database as `resources.db.*` something like `resources.mydb.*` wouldn't work as default gateway!

Comment: So I changed the code to reflect Sam's suggestion and was faced with a different error. Turns out that the pdo extensions weren't installed properly on the server. After fixing this, I got yet another error suggesting incorrect login credentials to the server... which was progress. I then worked out that the credentials referred to by resources.db.params.[...] need to be in speech marks. Having corrected all of these things... i'm now up and running. Hope this info helps someone else at some point, and thanks, Sam, for suggesting the change to using resources.db instead of the config suff.